# Product of factorial in haskell

Tags: python, haskell

I am trying to convert Python to Haskell but facing difficulty. I am very new in Haskell and only know the basics.
Here is the Python code I need in Haskell. Can someone help me?

Thanks.

```
import sys
fact=[]
def facto():
    mod=1000000007
    f1=1;f2=1
    for j in xrange(1,1000001):
        f1=f1*j%mod
        f2=f2*f1%mod
        fact.append(f2)
def main():
    facto()
    tc=int(sys.stdin.readline())
    for i in xrange(tc):
        n=int(sys.stdin.readline())
        sys.stdout.write("Case %d: "%(i+1))
        print fact[n-1]
main()
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried in Haskell? Be more specific about where you are having trouble, what errors are you getting, etc.

Comment: I googled and found haskell tutorial where somee built in function was mntion factorial `n = product [1..n] `mod` 1000000007` but this is taking more time. Thats why I asked here for help.

Comment: @JustinWood I googled and found haskell tutorial where some built in function was metion factorial `n = product [1..n] mod 1000000007` but this is taking more time. Thats why I asked here for help.

Comment: it isn't very clear what you are asking at this point. It sounds like you are just asking us to write the code for you. That is not the point of this site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for an entire program to be written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way of generating the "product of factorials" list using `scanl`:

```
p = 1000000007 :: Int64
mtimes a b = mod (a * b) p
facts = scanl mtimes 1 [1..]
prodfacts = scanl mtimes 1 facts
```

Note:

```
ghci> take 10 facts
[1,1,2,6,24,120,720,5040,40320,362880]

ghci> take 10 prodfacts
[1,1,1,2,12,288,34560,24883200,411327125,709563912]
```

Comment: I'd be more explicit: `p = 1000000007 :: Int64`, since on a 32-bit platform you'll get wrong results due to integer overflow.

Comment: The default type for numbers in Haskell is `Integer`, so adding `:: Int64` causes overflows, not prevents them.

Comment: We are performing arithmetic mod 10^9+7 so we don't anything more than an Int64.